# Infinite product of $\prod_{n=0}^{\infty }(1+\frac{1}{4^{n}})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a closed formula for the infinite product of $$\prod_{n=0}^{\infty }\left(1+\frac{1}{4^{n}}\right)\:?$$

Comment: You may write the product as the Pochhammer symbol $\left(-1;1/4\right)_{\infty}$. It depends if you want to see it as a closed form or not.

Comment: The most compact expression is in terms of Dedekind eta function. However, just like the other answers, it is more of a notation for this product than an actual evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the [$q$-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol) $(a,\,q)_n$, if $|r|<1$ then$$\prod_{n\ge0}(1-r^n)=(r;\,r)_\infty.$$Since $1+\tfrac{1}{4^n}=\tfrac{1-\tfrac{1}{16^n}}{1-\tfrac{1}{4^n}}$, your product is $\frac{(\tfrac{1}{16};\,\tfrac{1}{16})_\infty}{(\tfrac14;\,\tfrac14)_\infty}$.

As @Startwearingpurple notes, we can instead write$$\prod_{n\ge0}(1-r^n)=r^{-1/24}\eta(\tfrac{-i\ln r}{2\pi})$$in terms of the [Dedekind eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function), so your product is $2^{1/12}\frac{\eta\left(\tfrac{2i\ln2}{\pi}\right)}{\eta\left(\tfrac{i\ln2}{\pi}\right)}$.